# Regular expression for check mobile number

Tags: javascript, jquery, regex

Please anyone can explain me , that what is the meaning of this regular expression

```
var str = '^([0|+[0-9]{1,5})?([7-9][0-9]{9})$';
```

This regular expression is used for check mobile number , But I am not able to find out how to check mobile number with that regular expression

Please Let me know

Thanks,

Comment: Easy way to figure out what a regex means is to just plug it into regex101 (though this one appears to have problems, `[0|+[0-9]` matches 0 to 9, or a pipe, or a plus)

Comment: I am not aware about regex101 , thanks for suggestion

Comment: [Regular Expression Visualizer](https://jex.im/regulex/#!flags=&re=%5E(%5B0%7C%2B%5B0-9%5D%7B1%2C5%7D)%3F(%5B7-9%5D%5B0-9%5D%7B9%7D)%24)

Comment: this ^(\+?\d{1,4}[\s-])?(?!0+\s+,?$)\d{10}\s*,?$  expression is used for check mobile number is valid or not

Comment: You can refer this doc and testing regular expression below link 
https://www.freeformatter.com/regex-tester.html